# Finding Laurent series of $f(x)= \frac{1}{(z+1)(z+3)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(x)= \frac{1}{(z+1)(z+3)}$

for regions

1. $1<|z|<3$
2. $0<|z+1|<2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use partial fractions to decompose $f(x) = \frac {A}{z+1} + \frac {B}{z+3}$

The Taylor series for $\frac {1}{a-z}$ is $\frac 1a \sum_\limits {n = 0}^\infty (\frac {z}{a})^n$

If $|a|$ is inside the radius then use the Taylor series.

If not:

$\frac {1}{a-z} = \frac {1}{z}\frac {-1}{1-\frac {a}{z}} = -\frac 1z \sum_\limits {n = 0}^\infty (\frac {a}{z})^n = -\frac 1a\sum_\limits {n = -1}^{-\infty} (\frac {z}{a})^n$

And that should be enough to build your Laurent series.